# How to deny or reject FTP commands for some user on proftpd?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, proftpd

There works a FTP Server (proftpd) on Centos 6.5, Auth mech is AUTH_FILE and default ROOT is /var/ftp all User should put Files into this directory but only 2 User should get or list this files. Is it possible to deny some FTP Commands for a few Users?

My proftpd Config looks like:

```
DefaultRoot                     /var/ftp/
AuthPAMConfig                   proftpd
AuthOrder                       mod_auth_file.c  mod_auth_unix.c
RequireValidShell  off
AuthUserFile  /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
AuthGroupFile /etc/proftpd/ftpd.group
AuthPAM off
RequireValidShell off
```

The content of /etc/proftpd/ftpd.group is:

```
ftp_group:x:50:user1
```

And the user file /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd looks like:

```
user1:$1$somesaltblablablablablablablabd:9999:9999::/var/ftp:/bin/false
user2:$1$somesaltblablablablablablablabd:9999:9999::/var/ftp:/bin/false
user3:$1$somesaltblablablablablablablabd:9999:9999::/var/ftp:/bin/false
```

User1 should be the user who can't get or list Files on the FTP Server. Is it possible?

Comment: It's entirely possible. Did you read the documentation, e.g. http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch5.html ?

Comment: What section you mean, I can't find a section to deny or reject commands

Comment: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch5.html#AEN524 should give you a basis to start from. But I'd advise you to read the whole thing.

Comment: If I understand this section right it is to build a security tree for a user, but the user should use the same directory as the other users but without permission to run the get or list command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to this [Documentation](http://debian.asco.de/doc-etch/proftpd-doc/howto/Limit.html) (In the example section) I use LIMIT Command to reject the FTP Commands. The following was add to the proftpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/ftp>
 <Limit ALL>
      DenyAll
 </Limit>

 <Limit DIRS READ>
    AllowUser user1
    AllowUser user2
    DenyAll
 </Limit>
</Directory>
```

User3 can use the LIST Command (`ls`) but proftpd deny the command and return an empty result and the other User (User1 and User2) can use this Commands.